# Alternatives for replace() and matches()

Tags: xpath, xquery

i have to work with a given XPath/XQuery-Processor and i cannot use the replace() or matches() functions, because they are not supported. 
But i need their functionality.
What would be good alternatives?
i am trying to do something like this:

replace "-" symbols in a string with "", means i have to erase the minus symbols
e.g. : turn

```
"--ssam----ple----string"
```

into

```
"samplestring"
```

and later i need to 
look for a certain string pattern in the resulting string e.g.

```
matches("samplestring", [a-z]*st[a-z]*)
```

but since i cannot use replace or matches, i dont know how to realize this.

Thanks

Comment: What XQuery processor is there that does not support those functions? Just curious.

Comment: it is the XQuery processor of a xml database called XTC and i sucks that these functions are not supported, it keeps giving me an "unknown function" error

Comment: Then let's hope they did at least implement `translate()` and `contains()` (I don't have much hope for `string-to-codepoints()`).

Answer (score 2):

In your particular cases, consider [fn:translate()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-translate):

```
translate('--ssam----ple----string', '-', '')
```

and [fn:contains()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains):

```
contains('samplestring', 'st')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one more solution (provided that your processor supports codepoint functions):

```
contains(
  codepoints-to-string(
    string-to-codepoints("--ssam----ple----string")[. ne 45]
  )
, "st")
```